# Stochastic random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, variance, means

Let $X(t) = \int_0^t W(s) \mathrm{d} s$
for $t \geq 0$.
Find the mean, variance and distribution function of the random
variable $X(2)$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://ibb.co/rvry7S4    I have uploaded the question here  please have a look

Comment: What is $W(t)$? Wiener process?

Comment: You can use the fact that $d(W_s s)=dW_ss+W_sds.$